# Как сохранить данные в приложении WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, save

1) Как работает сохранение в приложении WPF? Т.е. что происходит, когда я заново запускаю приложение? Всё начинается с нуля или данные в переменных сохраняются?

2)  Можно ли использовать собранное приложение из папки debug как полноценное приложение? Или это именно "особенная" версия приложения.

Я просто никак не могу понять, почему при повторном запуске все данные слетают, конкретно в моём случае считаются томаты. Т.е. выполнился таймер томат++, но после перезапуска всё начинается с нуля. Это нормально, или я что-то делаю не так? Может быть, у меня что-то с кодом не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Из коробки ничего никуда не сохраняется, программист должен сам
   озаботится сохранением и загрузкой стейта программы. Без этого программа запускается всегда как первый раз.
2. В принципе
   можно, но в теории приложение будет работать медленнее из-за кучи
   отладочного кода. Так что в прод такое лучше не пускать, дебаг он на
   то и дебаг - чтобы отладкой на нем заниматься.

Comment: А как сделать нормальный exe файл?
А как тогда сохранить данные?

Comment: нормальный - ну откомпильте в релизе и будет нормальный экзешник, есть еще паблиш. как сохранять - ну тут кто как. Лично я создаю класс где буду нужные данные хранить, сериализую его в джейсон и кладу в папку пользователя. Потом загружаю. так что вам по хорошему надо погуглить эти два вопроса. На них уже тысячу раз отвечали.

Comment: В обозревателе проекта найдите пункт Properties в нем Settings откройте, в таблице создайте поля с названиями переменных, доступ из кода Properties.Settings.Default.названиеполя   туда же можно из кода записать новое значение. Только обязательно нужно после всех изменений сохранить Properties.Settings.Default.Save()

Comment: @axmed2004 Большое спасибо, помогло.